# Run multiple neo4j instances on ubuntu-18.4 machine with different ports

Tags: docker, neo4j

I need to create 3 instances of neo4j on single ubuntu-18.4 machine  , with 3 different ports . I tried changing default_database setting in neo4j.conf file but of no use . Can i do it without using docker ? . Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure. You can forward port from docker inside to different ports in docker outside. Checkout this [Container Networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

Comment: Be aware that if these instances are for a cluster, the machine is a single point of failure and the cluster won't really be highly available.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can, and in fact I do all the time when setting up a cluster. You need to make sure you update all the ports. [This walkthrough](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/local-causal-cluster/#tutorial-local-cluster) tells you all you need to know.